# Why doesn't the shell find a file inside the current directory by its name alone?

Tags: command-line, apt, scripts

I downloaded VS Code's `.deb` file for Ubuntu. I renamed it to `vs.deb`.

Then I go to my downloads directory:

```
cd ~/Downloads
```

And now that I'm here, I try to install it:

```
sudo apt install vs.deb
```

And here's what I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done   
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done   
E: Unable to locate package vs.deb   
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'vs.deb'
```

But when I install it using `./vs.deb`, then it gets installed:

```
sudo apt install ./vs.deb
```

Why doesn't Linux accept the name of the file inside the same directory without requiring the relative path?

Comment: Is the current directory defined in any PATH statement? I think not therefore you need the ./ This is well known and not a stupid behavior.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install a .deb file via the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40779/how-do-i-install-a-deb-file-via-the-command-line) Quoting from [Braiam's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/769542): *"Even if you are on the directory with the package you need to give a path using `./` at the start"*

Comment: You are trying to install a file; so a path is required. Your command without a path is to download & install the package name you provided  (it's more secure to not make assumptions that it could be a file but be a package in an approved source).

Comment: @David: If you're talking about the `PATH` environment variable, e.g. `/usr/local/bin:/bin:...` then no, it would make no sense for `apt` to search `$PATH` for `.deb` files given as args.  The querent made a wrong assumption about the shell being relevant.  Your comment might be misleading to beginners who don't realize that it doesn't actually apply; I'd suggest deleting it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

What you experience is not related to the shell, but to how the `apt` command interprets the arguments on the command line.

It is primarily aimed at installing packages from the software repositories. By default, an argument to `apt` means the name of a package in the software sources. The message:

```
E: Unable to locate package vs.deb
```

clearly indicates that a package `vs.deb` does not exist in the software sources.

Still, `apt` allows you to directly install a downloaded `.deb` package file and resolve dependencies for it. You must give an explicit file path to indicate you want to install a `.deb` file. `./vs.deb` already indicates a file path: `./` means the current directory, so apt will find the `vs.deb` file in the current directory.

Actually, it is never the shell that "finds" a file. The shell just passes arguments to the application, and it is up to the application to interpret these arguments. At most, the shell does expansion (e.g. replacing `*` with all filenames or `~` with the full path of your home folder) or variable substitution (e.g. `$HOME` is replaced by the content of that variable).

Comment: Arguably, brace expansion _does_ qualify as "finding" the files.

Comment: `apt`'s predecessor, `apt-get`, could never take a `.deb` as a command line option, only a package name; you had to use `dpkg -i` to install a .deb file.  So there's historical precedent for Debian's higher-level package tools to *not* interpret args as paths, at least not by default.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- Brace expansion doesn't do anything related to files, it's a purely textual transformation. Wildcard expansion, on the other hand, does look for matching files.